# I can't connect to my vpn unless I connect to my server just before (OpenVPN)

Tags: openvpn, vps, connection, ovh

so I have successfully set up OpenVPN Servers on a VPS or dedicated server before, but whenever I set one up on a Server that has OVH GAME DDoS protection, it wont work properly.

So here is my procedure and where the issue comes in:
I install OpenVPN Server via a script:

wget https://git.io/vpn -O openvpn-install.sh

and then after that: bash openvpn-install.sh to set the DNS server to 1.1.1.1 and to set the first config name.

Then I can successfully connect to the VPN and it works fine until I disconnect from *both*, VPN and VPS Server. When I then wait like 30 minutes or longer and try to connect to the VPN again, it wont work, no matter what device and client I use (I tried OpenVPN Connect for android and the OpenVPN Client for PC.)

Here are the last lines that the OpenVPN Client log on my PC shows me:

```
Thu Mar 14 23:06:28 2019 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1552601188,WAIT,,,,,,
Thu Mar 14 23:08:34 2019 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Thu Mar 14 23:08:34 2019 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

Now, I can kinda "solve" this connection issue, if I connect to the server via SSH, do nothing exept that and then connecting to the VPN just works again... However that is no solution, as I dont want to be connecting all the time to my Server in order to get the VPN to connect.

*However that only happens with a Server that has the OVH GAME DDoS protection.*
(I had this issue with a Dedicated OVH GAME Server from SoYouStart.com before and now with the OVH GAME KVM-VPS from 100up.org [GAME-KVM 1 on their site])

On every other server I have installed OpenVPN on before, this does not happen.
For example other servers where I did the same steps and had 0 issues: NFO VPS, Digital Ocean VPS, "usual" OVH VPS and more.

So I thought, that maybe the OVH GAME Servers will go into a standby mode, where they wont allow connections unless something happens on the server directly.

Next idea would be to screen a infinitly pinging 1.1.1.1 or google.com and then hope it will keep the server awake. However I would like to know before, if anyone of you has another idea.

**tl;dr:**
If im disconnected from my VPN and VPS, wait 30 min and then try to connect to the VPN, it won't work. This only happens on OVH GAME DDoS protected servers.
Temporary solution is to connect to the VPS and then connect to the VPN and it works.

Thank you all a lot in advance!

Comment: i don't think anyone anticipated that you would try to run a VPN on a game server.

Comment: Thats true, however I know one vpn site that offers ovh game VPN. So it should somehow be possible. I mainly got them for the DDoS protection btw.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using road warrior OpenVPN install. That is mad glitchy I suggest installing SoftEther. There’s an easy setup link I’ll send you which will help you with OpenVPN. This sets up SoftEther fully and all you have to do is answer the questions that pop up which are part of the configuration (if it sounds hard it isn’t trust me) anyways use this on OS Ubuntu 16.04 and below. CentOS 7 and below. And Debian 9 and below. Debian 10 , Ubuntu 18.04 , and CentOS 8 cause issues.
Paste this in: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaysonvelagio/SoftetherAutoInstallMultiPlatform/master/Debian%20and%20Ubuntu/installer.sh && chmod +x installer.sh && ./installer.sh`

These are the commands Incase you need to restart the softether server:
/etc/init.d/vpnserver start - to start
/etc/init.d/vpnserver restart - to restart
/etc/init.d/vpnserver stop - to stop

For CentOS:
`yum install wget -y && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaysonvelagio/SoftetherAutoInstallMultiPlatform/master/Centos/installer.sh && chmod +x installer.sh && ./installer.sh`

Comment: Never execute commands from some random link if you don't understand them.